# How to pass complex objects via SignalR?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, signalr

There is an excellent tutorial on [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callserver) that explains how to pass .NET objects as parameters to Javascript and vice versa.  In that case it passes a `ChatMessage` object to and from.

However, the tutorial addresses a really simple object.  I'd like to see how to deal with complex .NET objects (that have other objects as properties) in Javascript.

For instance, consider the following object:

```
class Master {
    public List<QuarterHour> QuarterHours { get; set; }
    public List<string> Books { get; set; }
    public int EndDay { get; set; }
    public int StartDay { get; set; }
}

class QuarterHour {
    public MinuteInstance Minute {get; set;}
    public int HourStart { get; set;}
}

class MinuteInstance { 
    public bool Registered {get; set;}
    public int NumAttendees {get; set;}
}
```

In .NET, I can reference a value like this: `master.QuarterHours[2].Minute.Registered`.  My questions:

1. How would I do reference `master.QuarterHours[2].Minute.Registered` in the receiver method on the Javascript end?
2. How would I build the `Master` object in Javascript to be sent to the .NET end?

Comment: It would be serialized and converted to a JSON object, just like you would work with a `JsonResult` from an action.

Comment: also don't forget to make your classes **public** !!

Comment: I had similar problem, but finally I figured out that I forgot await my async function which returns complex object. My fault :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. You just send it and reference it the same way.
2. You'd pass (this is how it looks when you get it from the server):

> ```
> {
>     QuarterHours: [{
>         Minute: {
>             Registered: true,
>             NumAttendees: 1337
>         },
>         HourStart: 1
>     }],
>     Books: ["Game of Thrones", "Harry Potter"],
>     EndDay: 2,
>     StartDay: 3
> }
> ```

Comment: I just changed my payload from <string> to a (simple) complex type and it doesn't work anymore, the Send-Method in the hub doesn't get called like before. No error, nothing. Do you have any ideas?

public async Task SendCommonMessage(CommonMessage commonMessage)

Answer (score 8):

You would want to serialize your class into a JSON object.  There are many ways to accomplish this, but you can try [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to do it quick and easy.

If its not already included in your project, you can add this through Nuget with:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

The code would look something like:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(master);
```

Once this is passed to your client-side, you can then read from your JSON object like any other.  You can use the following javascript code to convert your SignalR string message to a JSON object:

```
var master = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + message + ")"));
var registered = master.QuarterHours[2].Minute.Registered;
```

You can also pass this through SignalR to the server and deserialize the JSON object using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in order to convert it to your C# classes.  Check out the documentation here for further details: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

Comment: the question was on how to pass complex objects to singalR, not how to serialize objects.

Comment: ...and one solution is by serializing objects into JSON.

Comment: If there is a native way to send complex objects (as explained in the other answer), using serialization is not really a "good" solution, but a workaround - especially because it seems that serialization is what SignalR does internally.. so basically you are rewriting part of the library.

Comment: I just used SignalR to send a .NET object. The client-side js receives a js object in the same structure. I didn't have to serialize it at all. Make sure the properties are public!

Comment: you do not need manually serialize objects in signalR. its already implemented in signalr lib