# Update clients in asp.net core 2.0 using SignalR

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am going through several examples on Asp.net Core WebAPI with SignalR where most of them are demonstrating simple chat application where this is what Hub returns:

```
return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message);
```

And this is how it gets called in Startup.cs

```
routes.MapHub<Chat>("chat");
```

The above example is good if message is not be send and updated to all the clients. In my case I have several APIs to be called whenever a data is changed:

Like Bank Transaction is done, I have to update ledger and several other reports at client side. But I don't see any option to pass Json.

Not finding exactly how to do this so that WebAPI gets refreshed everytime a change is there in the database.

As far as I understood, here "chat" is the endpoint which will be called from the frontend.

In this case what will happen to the endpoint I have created so far. Have a look at the below code example:

This api is to be called every time an entry is done:

```
 public async Task<object> GetMarket(string marketshortcode)
        {
          Markets market = new Markets(marketshortcode);
          return market.GetMarket();
        }
```

and this the entry:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<object> sellCurUser([FromBody] SellCur model)
        {
            if (model != null)
            {
                SellCurUser suser = new SellCurUser();
                suser.sellcur = model;
                my addition code...

            }    
             return ....   
        }
```

There are several more endpoints which needs to be called at certain update/creation.

Now the point is how these apis will be changed or even not changed at all.

Do anyone have any example to understand it simply.

Comment: A message is a string, and your JSON is nothing but another string. So why do you need "an option"? It is already there.

Comment: I have already created api to show different data to the client, looking to implement SignalR now, my question is how the method will be called return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message); Don't have much clarity. I am not thinking about frontend now. just to get api refreshed as soon we post some row using api call.

Comment: Instead of a string you can also send complex objects (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350582/how-to-pass-complex-objects-via-signalr)

Comment: @Tester I edited my question to have more clarity, I am actually trying to fit all the available examples in my requirement but not able to get touched to it.

Comment: @JaidevKhatri I think you did not understand the functionality of signalr. You can use signalr for sending messages from server to client and also the opposite way.  Please read https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api. Maybe you should write more clear what you really like to do.

Comment: yeah, going through it.